# Changed domain admin password and now RDPMan logs me off servers with Error 2823

Tags: rdp

I had to change my domain admin password today and since on several servers I will get randomly booted/disconnected with the following error:

```
Disconnected from <server> (Error 2823)
```

I cannot find any information on error 2823, even `nethelp` gives me squat

```
P:\>net helpmsg 2823

The system cannot find message text for message number 0xb07 in the message file
 for NETMSG.
```

Anyone have info on this error.  The account keeps getting locked but I have no services running with this ID.

I only get kicked from some servers too, not all.

**EDIT**

Solution posted below.

Comment: Do you have any AD replication issues in your domain?  Maybe some of the servers are out of sync or otherwise not aware of the changes?

Comment: I do believe that is probably the cause, I had just never run into error 2823 before.

Comment: http://thenubbyadmin.com/2010/05/21/solved-rdp-disconnected-error-code-2825/  could you need to enable NLA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had a scheduled task running on a remote server on Alderaan that was mistakenly hard-coded to my old ID.

I managed to track down the box that was locking my account using this awesome tool [EventComb](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=18465).

[This blog helped me figure this all out.](http://blog.chrisconklin.com/?p=84)

The settings I used in the EventComb tool were as follows:

**SELECT TO Search/Right Click To Add**

- Select all DCs in Domain

**Choose Log Files to search**

- Check Security
- Uncheck all others

**Event Types**

- Check Success Audit
- Check Failure Audit
- Uncheck all others

**Event IDs**
- "4740"

Then press "Search".  It will take a few minutes to run and produce and output file of all accounts that have been locked.  The output will look similar to this (I added carriage returns for readability) :

```
4740,AUDIT SUCCESS,Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing,Wed Sep 18 04:05:49 2013,No User,A user account was locked out.    -
Subject:   Security ID:  S-1-5-18   Account Name:  DC-PRIMARY$   Account Domain:  Corp   Logon ID:  0x3e7    -
Account That Was Locked Out:   Security ID:  S-1-5-21-4144105501-2967912833-963096433-4827   -
Account Name:  userAdmin    Additional Information:   Caller Computer Name: WEBSERVER-01
```

Once I found out server WEBSERVER-01 was issuing the bad login to the domain controller it was easy to fix the issue.  Hope this helps someone in the future.